# How do I darken an entire webpage and display a floating, interactive box?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

This seems to be a really popular effect that websites will use to forcibly focus user attention. Are there different ways of doing this? Is there some easy JS library out there built for this effect that everyone uses? How do I display html and make the windows dragable?

I'm just beginning to learn webdesign, went through the w3schools tutorials on AJAX, JS, HTML5 and CSS. If anyone could point me in the direction of some libraries or tutorials I'd sure appreciate it!

Comment: http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/

Comment: Are you thinking of lightbox?  http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you a summary of how this works and a script that will help you do this.

You have an overlay of width and height 100% and a transparent background of black color(position:absolute). So this is made visible(via javascript) and over it you positon a box containing whatever you want to show at the center.

You can find the tutorial here: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/ (not my website)

Comment: I forgot to mention. Use jquery.blockUI plugin to do this easily on your pages.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal), right? It is a "window", and it is draggable.

Comment: he's talking about lightboxes in general, I suppose